# ABBYY FlexiCapture web service in workflow

Tags: web-services, rest, abbyy

I need to implement a custom workflow for a batch type. Inside this workflow it is necessary to communicate with another system through a web service (REST).
Is there any predefined API for ABBYY I can use?
I only found solutions to call ABBYY through other systems, not calling other systems from ABBYY.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to implement a solution inside Abbyy, but since I'm using FlexiCapture 11, only .Net Framework 3.5 is supported. Because I have to use objects which require .Net version 4.5 I've switched to the solution to call an external program from Abbyy which does all the web service implementation.